# Geocoding android - Longitude and Latitude values incorrect

Tags: android

I Have an address that I would like to know the coordinates of. For instance the address is "Skillman Ave" Queens, NY. The coordinates is: `40.747281, -73.9283169` according to maps.google.com. In my app I have a function like this:

```
 public GeoPoint addressToGeo(String adr) {
    Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this);
    List<Address> address = null;
    GeoPoint coordinates;


    try {
        address = coder.getFromLocationName(adr, 1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    if (address == null) {
        return null;
    }
    Address location = address.get(0);
    location.getLatitude();
    location.getLongitude();

    coordinates = new GeoPoint((int) (location.getLatitude() *1E6),
                      (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));

     return coordinates;
}
```

Which takes an address as parameter, and hopefully it will return the coordinates. My debugger says the the first element in the list adress contains this information:

```
[Address[addressLines=[0:"Skillman Ave",1:"Queens, New York",2:"Amerikas forente stater"],feature=Skillman Ave,admin=New York,sub-admin=Queens,locality=Queens,thoroughfare=Skillman Ave,postalCode=null,countryCode=US,countryName=Amerikas forente stater,hasLatitude=true,latitude=40.747281,hasLongitude=true,longitude=-73.9283169,phone=null,url=null,extras=null]]
```

which seems correct if you look at the latitude and longitude variables. But when I type in this code:

```
GeoPoint test; 
test = addressToGeo("Skillman Ave"); 
double latitude = test.getLatitudeE6(); 
double longitude = test.getLongitudeE6(); 

String lat = Double.toString(latitude);
String lng = Double.toString(longitude);
String total = lat + " " + lng; 
toAdress.setText(total);
```

the toAdress textField will contain `4.0747281E7, -7.3928316E7` The comma is not in the right spot, and what is the `E7` in the end of each double?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
String lat = Double.toString(latitude);
String lng = Double.toString(longitude);

lat= (float) (lat / 1E6);
lng = (float)(lon / 1E6);

System.out.println("lat :" + (float) lat / 1E6);
System.out.println("lon :" + (float) lon / 1E6);
```

Answer (score 4):

'E7' is notation meaning that you need to multiply by 10^7 to get the actual number. In this case it would give you 40747281. You then need to format that into a proper coordinate.

Ankit's code looks like it might do that, but test to make sure.

Answer (score 2):

You've got all the right data, so this question is really about formatting a double. Use [DecimalFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).

Use this to display the lat/lon points in your test:

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.0000000");
String lat = formatter.format(test.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6); 
String lon = formatter.format(test.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6); 
toAddress.setText(lat + " " + lon);
```